# Heroku - Can't access or create database JSON data of ruby app, error HTTP 500

Tags: json, ruby, database, heroku, production

I'm having a problem in Production when accessing the JSON (let's call it *mydata.json*) where I store the data of my ruby webapp, deployed with Heroku. The way I access the download of this file is by putting into the browser:

**my-heroku-page.herokuapp.com/mydata.json**

but I get the HTTP 500 error page.
Always using the browser, when I try to create it I get the Ruby page:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

First I must say I'm using the same source code I used for another webapp that is actually working, I just modified the database.yml according to my new host, database, username and password. The previous webapp was perfectly working, i.e I could create the table and access the data. Secondly the error doesn't occur with localhost.

I tried to create a Dataclip in Heroku:

```
Select * from mydata order by created_at desc;
```

but I get the error:

> "Your query couldn't be created."
>   ERROR:  relation "mydata" does not exist
>   LINE 3: FROM mydata

Plus when I check the heroku pg:info I get 0 Tables

```
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 0/20
PG Version:  9.5.5
Created:     2016-11-15 08:30 UTC
Data Size:   7.4 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
Add-on:      postgresql-convex-54172
```

It seems like *mydata.json* is not created in production, but in localhost is working fine and I can create/download a blank one. I'm sure I'm missing something easy here, maybe in the database.yml.

I will edit the question if additional info are required. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Simone

Comment: put it on public folder

Comment: The fact is that I can see public folder files such as `foo/robots.txt` or the `foo/favicon.ico` but I can't see `foo/mydata.json`. While on my other webapp everything is working fine